# Why does tns run android work but when I add --bundle it does not

Tags: webpack

I am trying to get webpack up and running in my nativescript application using these instructions https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack.

The command tns run android works pefectly but when I try to run tns run android --bundle everything goes haywire.

All the error messages I get are all the same and one of them looks like this

```
ERROR in ./pages/settings/settings.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/settings/settings.html' in 
'C:\Users\stull\Desktop\forritun\SecondLudusApp\app\pages\settings'
 @./pages/settings/settings.component.ts 171:22-63
 @./app.routing.ts
 @./app.module.ts
 @./main.ts
```

At the end I receive this message

```
Webpack compilation complete.
Unable to apply changes on device: "devicename". Error is: Executing webpack 
failed with exit code 2..
Executing after-watch hook from "path"
Stopping tsc watch
Executing after-watch hook from "path"
```

Has anyone had any similar problems and managed to fix them?

In case it helps, here is also my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "lib": [
        "es6",
        "es5",
        "dom",
        "es2015.iterable"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [
            "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
            "./node_modules/*"
        ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "platforms",
    "**/*.aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Write a more descriptive title

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.

Running with tns run android allowed me to do

```
templateUrl: "pages/something/something.html"
```

Running with webpack does not accept this writing style. 
It accepts this version

```
templateUrl: "./something.html"
```

And for the css files that I used from another component I had to do

```
styleUrls: ["./../otherComponent/otherComponent.html"]
```